# Getting unexpected changelist during svn merge of folder of different branches

Tags: svn

I have 2 branches accos_2.1.3b_ludz and accos_2.1.3_ludz. I made the following changes to the /WebcContent/WEB-INF/lib folder accos_2.1.3b_ludz :
[image]
[image]

They just basically updates to the newer version of jar file. I'm trying to merge the changes to accos_2.1.3 branch

Using `svn merge` command with `--dry-run` gives me the following:

```
 C:\Users\linhou\Teamforge\accos_2.1.3b_ludz\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib>svn merge ^
 More?  ^^/Accos/branches/ludwig/accos_2.1.3b_ludz/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib ^
 More? ^^/Accos/branches/ludwig/accos_2.1.3_ludz/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib --dry-run
--- Merging differences between repository URLs into '.':
A    hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar
A    antlr-2.7.6rc1.jar
D    antlr-2.7.7.jar
D    hibernate-core-4.2.21.Final.jar
```

What I don't understand is why hibernate-core.4.2.18.Final.jar is marked `A` instead of `D` and hibernate-core-4.2.21.Final.jar is marked `D` instead of `A`. Given the accos_2.1.3b is the source and accos_2.1.3 is the target, so I'm expecting the `A`s and `D`s to be interchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html), your command line has the following format:

```
svn merge SOURCE1 SOURCE2 [TARGET_WCPATH]
```

This generates the differences to apply to go ***from*** `SOURCE1` ***to*** `SOURCE2`.
So in you case, this generates the differences to apply to go ***from*** branch `accos_2.1.3b_ludz` ***to*** branch `accos_2.1.3_ludz`. What you observed is fully compliant with this explanation.

For your expected output, you just need to invert the arguments, as follows:

```
svn merge .../accos_2.1.3_ludz/... .../accos_2.1.3b_ludz/... --dry-run
```